No drives detected - TrueNAS scale with a Dell PowerEdge R710 Perc H200
I got a Dell PowerEdge R710 with a Perc 6. I purchased an H200 and flashed it to IT mode, first using this post. Then following this Reddit post.
After both attempts at flashing I am unable to see the 2 WD Red 3TB drives connected to the back plane. Neither in the h200 BIOS (ctrl-c) topology map or in TrueNAS scale. Both flashing attempts were successful.
When the H200 loads at startup I get the message:

LSI corporation MPT boot ROM, no supported devices found.

s2fp19.exe -c 0 -list

Showed correct board name and firmware. h200 IT mode (0x2213 (IT)) and 2, etc… I am using sff-8087 to sff-8087 right angle cables to go from the h200 to the r710 backplane. I have tested the HDDs in a Windows system and they work.
